# Words to describe a person who frequently asks questions even though they know the answer

Tags: phrase-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I have an annoying friend that he frequently asks me questions in which he'll be the one to answer at the end if I can't answer his questions. Here the situation goes:

> *Friend: Hey Jay, do you know the medical term where the nerves intersect, i.e. in the spinal column, that's why right brain hemisphere controls the left side of the body and vice versa?*
>   Me: No. I really have no idea. Sorry.
>   *Friend: It is called "decussation".*
>   Me: Oh okay.
>   *Friend: Now, what do you call a person who frequently asks questions even though they know the answer?*
>   Me: Hmmm I don't have the slightest idea.
>   *Friend: It is ______, Jay. You really need to read books.*
>   Me: WTF!
>   *(annoyed)*

Is there a way to describe this kind of personality?

Comment: a "trivia show-off"?

Comment: Also, *riddler* might fit but a riddler asks riddles instead of trivial questions. For example, the Riddler (adversary of Batman) has this characteristic.

Comment: An old marriage.

Comment: jackass or turkey work

Comment: "Lawyer".  In fact, they are taught to not ask questions in court that they don't know the answer to.

Comment: My Ph.D. supervisor / any academic...

Comment: A teacher (one would hope).

Comment: In the context of the example given, answering with your friend's name seems like a competent comeback.

Comment: Except some made-up answers, none of the answers so far is about "asking questions". It is not just about showing off your knowledge.This is a very specific question and not a puzzle game. Although, I doubt there is a specific word for this.

Comment: @ermanen: as I read it, the OP doesn't seem oriented toward the "asking questions" aspect of the circumstances described herein. Rather, OP requests a single-word with pejorative connotations to describe a personality that is annoying because that person frequently asks questions even though they know the answer. I would agree that there is not a specific word to describe all the particulars, there are however more general terms for describing such a personality.

Comment: @ermanen - my comment wasn't an attempt to be disagreeable, but rather to relate how I read the thrust of the OP differently, as an attempt to find pejorative language to express annoyance concerning a personality who frequently annoyed by ... I'm just dialoguing with ya, ermanen, I may be off in right field. It's been known to happen. Hopefully OP is monitoring their submission, hey? Could happen. ;-)

Comment: The difficulty in composing concise and unambiguous language really comes to the fore when trying to compose an EL&U question, does it not, @ermanen?

Answer (score 26):

***Didactic*** as defined by Google: *in the manner of a teacher, particularly so as to treat someone in a patronizing way.*

Comment: I like this. A "didactic Socrates" covers all points of the question, but falls out of the single-word-request purview.

Comment: Also "didactic nerd" fits but "didactic" doesn't necessarily cover "asking questions".

Comment: Huh. I've never known didactic to explicitly refer to anything patronizing.

Comment: @PatrickM It is not a single-word request.

Comment: The expression **didactic way** is by far more common than "didactic person". See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+is+didactic%2Che+was+didactic%2Cdidactic+person%2Cdidactic+way&year_start=1920&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20is%20didactic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20didactic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdidactic%20person%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdidactic%20way%3B%2Cc0)  *Didactic poem/poetry* and *works*; however, are most commonly used.

Comment: @PatrickM: Or how about "Socratic"? Don

Comment: @Jaeger Jay - do you realize that the OP bears a single-word-request tag?

Comment: @LittleEva Many people who added the 'single-word-request' tag are really looking for a single *term* rather than a single *word*, and are not aware of other relevant tags. Since the tags are not mutually exclusive, there is no reason for them to expect that adding 'single-word-requests' will restrict the answers to only those answers. Rather, the tag gets the attention of the people who like that sort of question. This question explicitly asks for "a way to describe" and for "words to describe".

Comment: vladkornea, while I am quite aware of all that you have posted, many users who only tag for single-words are looking exclusively for single-words. "way/words to describe" may not mean phrases. My comment, however, was addressed to the OP who, like yourself, is a relatively new user. Almost all of the users who have responded to this OP, including you & I, have suggested single-words. If, in addition to single-words, phrases are acceptable, then it is helpful, and productive, for that fact to be reflected in one's tag choices. The purpose of my comment was to encourage that awareness.

Comment: @LittleEva People who are not accepting multiple-word terms can state so in the question. You're not offering advice on which tags should be added here, it sounds like you're merely advising people to omit the 'single-word-requests' tag from questions in which other types of answers are also accepted.

Comment: vladkornea, no. The best way to get that variety is to specify it in tag selection.

Comment: Now this question is tagged 'phrase-requests', and is not tagged 'single-word-requests'. This is worse. The OP is clearly looking for a single *term*. Whether the term is a word or a phrase is not relevant here. It makes absolutely no sense to treat tags as mutually exclusive.

Comment: @vladkornea I am looking for a term - word or words. The problem here is that there is no tags for words-request - technically, 2 or more words request.

Answer (score 12):

**[wiseacre](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wiseacre)**

> A person with an affectation of wisdom or knowledge, regarded with
>   scorn or irritation by others; a know-it-all.

Another choice, that's an Americanism is

**[wisenheimer](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wisenheimer)**

> A person who behaves in an irritatingly smug or arrogant fashion,
>   typically by making clever remarks and displaying their knowledge.

Comment: I've never heard "wisenheimer" ever, and I'm American. Also you should know that "wiseacre" is a very clear euphemism for a less work-safe word that starts the same.

Comment: @neminem - wiseacre's etymology appears independent of wiseass. Most sources attribute its root to Middle Dutch wijssegger. The two words in my answer may not be as commonly used as they once were, but it's easy to find current usages of both.

Comment: Huh, really? That's neat, I really thought one was a clear derivation of the other, like when you say it "hurts like a mother", when that is clearly not what you actually *meant*. Neat. I definitely *hear* "wiseacre" occasionally, just in situations where the person clearly meant to say "wiseass" but felt he couldn't.

Comment: This american is familiar with *wisenheimer*, though I think it's dated, like *poindexter*.

Comment: @stevesliva: What region are you from? I'm from the Midwest (Ohio/Wisconsin) and have never heard _wisenheimer_. I have heard _wiseass_, but more frequently I hear _smartass_.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce doubt I've heard it spoken unless it was on TV from the 60s.  Like "golly."

Comment: But not totally dying out: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wisenheimer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwisenheimer%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @AndrewCoonce, I'm from the eastern part of the U.S., just below the [Mason-Dixon line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%E2%80%93Dixon_line),  and I've heard the term wisenheimer, but not in decades; whether one has heard it before could be dependent on one's age.

Answer (score 7):

I think that the best term is [**Pedant**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedant).  From the Merriam-Webster site:

> **Pedant** 
>   : a person who annoys other people by correcting small errors and giving too much attention to minor details

also

> one who makes a show of knowledge

and

> one who is unimaginative or who unduly emphasizes minutiae in the presentation or use of knowledge

Comment: While someone who does ask questions in this way could be a pedant, I don't think of that when someone says the word "pedant". Rather, I imagine someone who nitpicks others' statements and generally gives unnecessary corrections or bits of information (much like your definitions imply).

Comment: I'm going to be pedantic here and alert you of the fact that there is a space before the colon.

Comment: I think @Eric s answer gives away his pedant side :-). I guess my picking on his comment shows that I'm a pedant as well :-)  (pun intended in both sentences)

Comment: Pedant is a better fit than anything else given so far.

Comment: @Eric - You're right.  I was thinking that, to be more precise, you would need more than a single word.  Socratic pedagogue, maybe?  That would be pretty clunky.

Answer (score 6):

Whereas the behavior OP describes is a form of **one-upmanship**, one who regularly engages in such behavior is usually considered to be lacking in self-esteem, and so, by way of compensation, becomes a **boastful** person, or a **boaster**.

---

> [**one-upmanship**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one-upmanship)
>   *noun*:
>
> • behavior in which someone tries to get an advantage by doing, saying, or having better things than someone else
>
> • the art or practice of outdoing or keeping one jump ahead of a friend or competitor. “engaged in a round of verbal *one-upmanship*”
>
> First Known Use of one-upmanship: 1952; (Merriam-Webster *online*)

---

> [**boast**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boast)
>
> *intransitive verb*: **1**: to puff oneself up in speech : speak vaingloriously
>
> *transitive verb*: **1**. to speak of or assert with excessive pride. **2 a**: to possess and often call attention to (something that is a source of pride). “*boasts* a new stadium”

---

> [**boaster**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/boaster) *noun*: someone who boasts. “I'm tired of hearing about that *boaster's* new car.”
>
> *Synonyms*: blower, blowhard, boaster, brag, braggadocio, bragger, cockalorum, cracker [*chiefly dialect*], gascon, gasconader, swaggerer, vaunter. Related Words blusterer, cock; self-advertiser, self-dramatizer, self-promoter. (all linked definitions courtesy of Merriam-Webster *online*)

Answer (score 6):

I call them "Ask-holes". Those are people who ask a question who either know the answer, or ask but don't wait for (or want) the answer.

Comment: The Urban Dictionary does in fact contain examples of the term (*don't know why I was surprised*), [**ask-hole**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=askhole), however those definitions neither accord with yours nor bear upon this OP. Could you point to some examples of usage, please?

Answer (score 5):

I submit Socratic as an adjective, as in the Socratic method.

> Socratic method, also known as method of elenchus, elenctic method, or Socratic debate, is named after the classical Greek philosopher Socrates. It is a form of inquiry and discussion between individuals, based on asking and answering questions to stimulate critical thinking and to illuminate ideas.

<sup>Source: Wikipedia contributors. "[Socratic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method)." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, 3 Jul. 2015. Web. 13 Jul. 2015.</sup>

Using this to describe a person presupposes that their intent is principally to inform or teach, not just show off. However, continuously interjecting a conversation with *non-sequiturs* like this is certainly more annoying than informative, so your subject in question is at best oblivious and at worst attention seeking (or even down-putting, intending for the listeners to feel inferior or belittled).

Comment: The Socratic method is a method of reasoning, wherein questions are intended to advance a thought process. This person is merely asking people what something is called, there is no argument being advanced.

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of words or phrases.  The better you know the person, the better equipped you are to choose the right one. I suggest:

**"a know-all"**

> - (noun) (informal, derogatory) a person who pretends or appears to know a great deal [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/know-all)

**"a pseudointellectual"**

> - (noun) a person exhibiting intellectual pretensions that have no basis in sound scholarship. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pseudo-intellectual?s=t)

**"a show-off"**

> - (noun) a person given to pretentious display. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/show-off?s=t)

I myself would call him **"a bore"** or **"soporific"**.

Comment: Show-off is good. The word pseudo-intellectual refers only to individuals who have little knowledge or none but pretends to be smart. My OP isn't showing any pretensions. In fact, he's somewhat bragging the things he know.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest "quizmaster", though I recognize that's probably not a sufficiently devastating thing to put in that dialogue's blank.

Answer (score 2):

Someone people think of them as a human dictionary or someone who loves patronizing. Or a worrywart- if they can't reassure themselves of something they show know, they tend to ask questions.

Other words are: nerdy, insecure, egoistatical, likes to elicit a lot, teacher(if it was a trick or rhetorical question),cocky or cheeky and studious.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the french word ["cuistre"](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/cuistre) that I can think of for that description, I would say **Pedant** or **Prig** or  **All-knowing pedant** or even **Conceited pedant**.

Comment: To be pedantic, the word pedant describes a very different character trait.

Answer (score -3):

The word you are looking for is DISINGENUOUS meaning one who professes to know less than they actually do.

Comment: How do you know he is disingenuous? This answer is not that related to the question.

Comment: I don't think this word fits -- he doesn't profess not to know the meanings of these words.  Someone disingenuous has the goal of convincing the other person that they themselves are *naive*, not knowledgeable.

Comment: Maybe you meant to write "who professes to know MORE than they actually do." In a Socratic dialog, Socrates is the one who professes to know less than he really does (hence, he's in an ironic mode, or simply the eiron), whereas his interlocutor, the alazon, is a braggart of sorts who professes/pretends to know more than he actually does. Socrates, of course, puts him in his place! Don